# M3 enumerators don't have their own scheme?

Tags: rascal

While working with M3 models, we had a discussion on enumerators within the M3 model.
While it is possible to get the enumerators contained in the M3 model by checking the @extends annotation for 'java+interface:///java/lang/Enumerator', I wondered why the enumerator did not get its own scheme ('java+enum').
Is there a specific reason for not having an enumerator scheme?

Comment: Can you provide an example of some sort where you have to do this? I am not sure I completely understand the question since M3 does have a "java+enum" scheme for enum types.

Comment: Oh I see. So it is just the functions to get enums that are missing. That is easily solved. Thanks.